# udev hammering CPU with bluetooth plugging events

Tags: udev, bluetooth

I just installed [Lakka](https://www.lakka.tv/) on an ASRock 1135G7 and udevd is hammering one core with constant logs of an usb device being reconnected. WiFi works but bluetooth is listed as the culprit in the logs. lspci is listing an Intel device with identifier 2725 which Googles to the Wi-Fi 6E AX210. rfkill is set to allow all.

```
Lakka:~ # rfkill list
1: phy0: wlan
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
645: hci0: bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of which kernel are you running? There could be issues with the AX210 chip if you're running an old kernel.

Comment: Yeah Lakka 4.x uses 5.10 which is the problem. The 5.0 dev branch uses 5.15 and BT works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe issue with firmware?  You can try to add `iommu=soft` at grub (found usually at `/etc/default/grub`).  The line would like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash iommu=soft"`.  That may help.

The details how it works can be found at [gentoo's wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/IOMMU_SWIOTLB)